# Record Statistics for Discrete Random Walks

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, discrete, random-process

I code a random walk of length 100 drawn from a LaplaceDistribution:

```
Accumulate[RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[0, 1], 10000]]
```

I am having trouble counting the number of record events in a discrete random walk. A record occurs at time t if the value of the random walk at time t is greater than all values of the walk for all times less than t. I want a function that will let count the number of records that occur in a walk of length n.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you first generate 10000 samples and then only keep 100 of them randomly?

Comment: I've realised it is completely pointless to do that lol.

Comment: No problem :) Just wanted to clarify if there's some deeper meaning behind it that i missed.

Comment: Is the mean number of records in such a walk the desired end result? If so, then n `Binomial[2 n, n]/2^(2 n - 1)` with `n` the step number suffices...

Answer (score 9):

Here's one take:

```
path = Accumulate[RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[0, 1], 1000]];
records = FoldList[Max, path];

ListPlot[{
  path,
  records
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`records` has lots of duplicates in it. It's a list where in each position we have the largest value up to that point. If we take the union of the values (or use `DeleteDuplicates`), we get the unique largest-so-far values, and if we count those we get the desired answer:

```
Length@Union[records]
```

> 52

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Comment: @smallscot How this example is done in 3D?

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon It is exactly the same, but of course you have to have a scoring function adapted to 3D vectors. It could, for example, be `Max@*Norm`.

Answer (score 6):

Let's generate data from a random walk first

```
SeedRandom[42]
walkdata = Accumulate[RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[0, 1], 100]]
```

[image: random walk data plot]

, then one way to get what you want is with a `Fold`:

```
Last@Fold[
  Function[{state,newvalue},
    With[{currentrecord=state[[1]],recordcounter=state[[2]]},
      If[newvalue > currentrecord,
        {newvalue,recordcounter+1},
        state
      ]
    ]
  ],
  {0,0},
  walkdata
]
```

> 33

During the fold we keep track of the `currentrecord` and the number of records (starting with `{0,0}`) and update it when we find a higher value, otherwise we keep the old. The endresult is the last record and the number of records we encountered from which we just keep the number of record updates (with `Last`).

Comparing it with C.E.s solution this mainly trades some code clarity (if that's most important definitely go with C.E.s version) for some potential speed up by saving the overhead of the `Union` function call. If you are dealing with long random walks or doing a lot of them this might become relevant. There is also the additional option to `Compile` if you need better performance.